# Smoothly working with AWS CN outside of CN

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

In my project I'm working heavily with AWS and we're currently finishing our cloud migration. As our biggest market is China & the latencies as well as data transfer rates from Tokyo as well as Seoul if you're located in China are really not that awesome, we're also starting to build up infrastructure in AWS CN.

We're managing everything with Terraform and we're really happy with it, but even applies without updated artifacts in CN take ages. The latencies are as expected slow from Europa, but what we did not expect are the data transfer rates. If artifacts need to be pushed to CN, most of the time we can't even reach 20kB/s.

We're now playing around with an EC2 build agent in AWS CN so we can cache app dependencies independently & apply directly from inside AWS CN. That makes life a little bit easier, but as soon as we need some new dependencies from maven central or our team internal artifactory, the next hours will be spend blocked.

So to sum this up: **if you're a developer located outside of china (or probably also in china)  but working with AWS CN, what's your setup?**

I'm super happy with any tips that can improve our daily work!

Comment: Hey @tpschmidt we are also working with AWS China and experiencing slow performance when users in China try to fetch images from our S3 bucket in Singapore. I would love to have a quick chat and learn from each other. Send me email at rotem@supereffective.com